# function with multiple arguments in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function to increment a mutable `int` by a specified amount.

```
let increase var:int ref amount = (var := !var+amount;var);;
```

This is what I came up with, but it produces errors. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your only problem is in the specification of the type of `var`. You need to use parentheses:

```
# let increase (var: int ref) amount = var := !var + amount; var;;
val increase : int ref -> int -> int ref = <fun>
```

For what it's worth, the type specification is optional. OCaml will infer the type.

(I would personally consider having the function return `unit`, which would make it analogous to the built-in function `incr`.)

Comment: @gasche: `incr` has type `int ref -> unit`. And it looks like the return from your function is pointless also -- it is always going to return `var`

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. I agree on the function return being pointless.